# How to securely store LWPCookieJar objects in python?

Tags: python, cookielib

I'm using a `cookielib.LWPCookieJar` object in Python 2.6 to save cookies and re-load them on future invocations of my script. The `save()` method produces files with the default permissions - that is, other users on my system can read (and presumably then use) cookies I save this way.

It seems to me that persistent cookies should usually be saved in a user-only readable file (umask 077), for security. Is there a way to do this without re-implementing the `save()` method in my own subclass?

Comment: What about building a fresh LWPCookieJar instance each time the script is run?

Comment: That's what I'm doing. I make a fresh `LWPCookieJar`, and use the `load()` and `save()` methods for persistence. These methods don't seem to save things in a very secure way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that this is important -- sessions IDs are often saved as cookies.

Would it suffice to save the cookie to a file in a directory which only the user can access?

```
os.mkdir( myTmpDir, 0700 )
// Now save the CookieJar in there...
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. It seemed like the right balance between idealism (setting permissions of the actual LWP file) and elegance (only one line of extra code).